# C++ error initializing array

Tags: c++

I want to initialize the array car.places[2][3]
but there's always zero in the array.
Please can someone tell me what I´m doing wrong,
here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class reserv
{
public:
  int places[2][3];
} car;


int main () {

car.places[2][3] = (
            (1, 2, 3),
            (4, 5, 6)
        );

for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
      cout << i << "," << j << " " << car.places[i][j] << endl;
    }
}

    return 0;
}
```

I get this warning form the compiler:

```
>g++ -Wall -pedantic F_car_test.cpp
F_car_test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
F_car_test.cpp:16:11: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [
-Wunused-value]
       (1, 2, 3),
           ^
F_car_test.cpp:16:14: warning: right operand of comma operator has no effect
[-Wunused-value]
       (1, 2, 3),
              ^
F_car_test.cpp:17:11: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [
-Wunused-value]
       (4, 5, 6)
           ^
F_car_test.cpp:17:14: warning: right operand of comma operator has no effect
[-Wunused-value]
       (4, 5, 6)
              ^
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: "Theres always zero in the array" What do you mean? You are getting only zero?

Comment: Never mind! I read it wrong..

Comment: You're not initializing the array, you're assigning to it. You can't assign to arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it after the declaration without a loop.

Here is how to do it in a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        car.places[i][j] = 1 + 3 * i + j;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initialize once an object for a struct/class is created; it's called initialization for a reason. Initialize it this way

```
#include <iostream>

struct reserv
{
  int places[2][3];
} car = {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}};


int main()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
      std::cout << i << "," << j << " " << car.places[i][j] << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This record

```
car.places[2][3]
```

denotes element places[2][3] of data member places of class reserv (or more precisely of object car).

The array was already created as a part of object car that you defined in the global name space.

Write instead

```
class reserv
{
public:
  int places[2][3];
} car  = { {
            {1, 2, 3},
            {4, 5, 6}
         } };
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you can only initialize arrays with initializer lists upon declaration. Since in this case your array is a class member, you can (and should) do it in the constructor.

```
 reserv::reserv():places{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}{};
```

You must enable `std=c++0x` in order to use this.